# Why is Gridview.count not filling out the space with my dynamic content

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a gridview starting from the second column. The first card is just a static card with a button in it. So the second card starting should be dynamic.

All the cards have the same width and height. So basically they all should look like the first card (Add a new dog)

But it's not filling out the space as I expected it would.

[image]

Here is part of my code from the body section:

```
body: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
      //bg image
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(Images.bgYellow), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      ),
      //content
      SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        left: true,
        right: true,
        top: false,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3 * SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal),
            child: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    children: [
                      //add card
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 1 * SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical,
                            horizontal: 2 * SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                              spreadRadius: 2,
                              blurRadius: 8,
                              offset: Offset(
                                  0, 2), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  const IconData(0xe901,
                                      fontFamily: 'icDog'),
                                  color: muddyBrown,
                                  size: 20 * SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5),
                                Text(
                                  "ADD A NEW  DOG",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: muddyBrown,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 4 *
                                          SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal),
                                )
                              ],
                            )),
                      ),
                      //dynamic content
                      StateBuilder<PetState>(
                          observe: () => _petStateRM,
                          builder: (context, model) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                ...model.state.pets.map((pet) =>
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.pushNamed(
                                            context, petDetailRoute);
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            vertical: 1 *
                                                SizeConfig
                                                    .blockSizeVertical,
                                            horizontal: 2 *
                                                SizeConfig
                                                    .blockSizeHorizontal),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                              color: Colors.grey
                                                  .withOpacity(0.5),
                                              spreadRadius: 2,
                                              blurRadius: 8,
                                              offset: Offset(0,
                                                  2), // changes position of shadow
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          //dynamic data => Photo + Name
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              width: 100.0,
                                              height: 100.0,
                                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                                color:
                                                    const Color(0xff7c94b6),
                                                image: new DecorationImage(
                                                  image: new NetworkImage(
                                                      "${pet.photo}"),
                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                ),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    new BorderRadius.all(
                                                        new Radius.circular(
                                                            50.0)),
                                                border: new Border.all(
                                                  color: muddyBrown,
                                                  width: 4.0,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                                            Text(
                                              "${pet.name}",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 4 *
                                                      SizeConfig
                                                          .safeBlockHorizontal,
                                                  color: muddyBrown,
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ))
                              ],
                            );
                          }),
                    ],
                  )
                )),
    ]));
```

Comment: The two small cards must have the same size ?

Comment: Yes all the same size. Note that the first card (add dog) is not dynamic. So the dynamic card is the second card

Comment: You talk about column, but the parent of the card is A Row, you should mention along what axis the dynamic grid view is need, and what is the number of the children required along the cross axis, kindly update the answer, or you might show us the required results

Comment: try to sketch your final solution so we can have a whole picture of it, then solution comes!

Comment: I just need a gridview with 2 colmns and the row are determined by the dynamic content

Answer (score 1):

What about simply adding the 'static' card to the 'dynamic' ones and then build one `GridView` with all of them together?

```
Widget newDogButton = Card(...);

//dynamic content
StateBuilder<PetState>(
  observe: () => _petStateRM,
  builder: (context, model) {
    return Column(
      children: [
          newDogButton,
          ...model.state.pets.map((pet) =>  // ...
```

That should take care of most of your layout issues automatically.

Comment: Doing like you suggest does not work as I would have expected => https://imgur.com/a/GXn7j1Q

Comment: Right, the `Column` should of course not be part of it, sorry.
Simply omit it and directly assign the list of cards to the GridView's children.

Answer (score 0):

Because `StateBuilder` return a widget. How about moving the **Whole GridView** inside it?

```
  ...
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(3 * SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal),
    child: StateBuilder<PetState>(
      observe: () => _petStateRM,
      builder: (context, model) {
        return GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [

            // The button "ADD A NEW  DOG" here,
            Container(...),

            //dynamic content here
            ...model.state.pets.map((pet) =>

              ...

            ).toList(),

      },
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Every grid item in GridView will have same height and width, if you want different dynamic height or width for different items, use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view), in your case:

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  itemCount: 2,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The situation:**
To me, this problem is not coming from your Dynamic content but from the `height` allowed to it to display it's content. Inside the `GridView.count` *constructor*, the default `childAspectRatio` value is `1.0`, meaning that the default max height of each child of the `GridView` is `deviceWidth / crossAxisCount` *(2 in your case)*.

**The problem:**
In order for each child to display correctly, it's height must not exceed this ratio (causing your overflowed error).

**My opinion:**
To solve this problem, I will either replace the dynamic content `StateBuilder<PetState>` with a static Widget which height will not exceed the ratio OR wrap the dynamic content `StateBuilder<PetState>` in a `SingleChildScrollView` to ensure that the `overflowed` error will not happen and the wrapper can produce the scroll effect to see the entire dynamic content.